# JAVA_HOME for the current java alternative

Tags: java, jdk

I have 2 jdk installed from downloaded `deb` packages from oracle: `jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.deb` and `jdk-21_linux-x64_bin.deb`

I can switch between the two versions by using `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

I have previously set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21-oracle-x64` in my `~/.bashrc` file

It still points to that directory when I switch to version 17

Is there a way to automatically set `JAVA_HOME` to the current java alternative that's activated, or do I have to manually edit its value each time I switch java versions?

Using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

After searching left and right, and noting that I'm already using a python version manager (`pyenv`), a node version manager (`nvm`), I have decided to do the same with java by using `SDKMAN!`, and just in doubt, I've set `JAVA_HOME` to `$HOME/.sdkman/candidates/java/current` which would point to the current activated java version installed from sdkman

I am aware that it just points to the `default` java version used by sdkman, and a project using a different version by using `.sdkmanrc` will fail while using that `JAVA_HOME` variable.

But system-wide, it will do for now